# How to avoid focusnode use in textformfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have used focusNode to focus cursor on text form field. But I defined global textformfield widget. but used focus node in single screen only. Now the problem is automatically all the field cursor gets activated. because of that common focusnode in widget. How we can set that only in slogin screen focus node will work or else that condition will avoid.

```
 FocusNode textFocusOnFirstField = FocusNode();

    TextFormField(
              // here use the variable in all the TextFormField
              // enabled: isEnable, // here use the variable in all the TextFormField
              focusNode: textFocusOnFirstField ,
              readOnly: readOnly,
```

Comment: Just check if you are in login page. 
page == 'login' ? textFocusOnFirstField : null

Comment: Just try `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` hope its help

Comment: that we can do only on click event

Comment: focusNode: focusNode ?? , What will be the other param to stop focusing on other fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

Use this in initState() so that it unfocuses all the textfield as soon as screen loads.

Comment: I have used that widget in more than 60 classes

Comment: It is like blocking keypad nothing else

Comment: How do we put condition of active one field and inactive others in this focusNode: textFocusOnFirstField

Comment: use focusnode parameter of TextFormField.
Example is given here. Please go through the article:
https://lakshydeep-14.medium.com/30-flutter-tips-ft16-focusnode-in-flutter-36236f2fd1e4